# Disappearing CiviCRM menu and Network Error

Tags: drupal

Recently I upgraded a from 4.7 to 5.1. All was well and then after a weekend suddenly the CiviCRM menu has disappeared and the dashboard and most other pages are displaying the error bubble:

> Network Error Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

Thinking it was some dastardly upgrade gremlin i decided to upgrade to 5.2 which has made no effect. I've checked the base url - with and without HTTPS. Any other troubleshooting tips I can try to resolve this?

UPDATE:

Struggling to turn on debugging via the UI so I enabled `define( 'CIVICRM_DEBUG_LOG_QUERY', 1 );` but I am none the wiser as no entries are marked [error].

F12 on the browser yielded no JS errors, but having the console open produced this [image: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<']

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This error typically means there's a JavaScript error.  Open your Developer tab in your browser (by pressing F12), go to the Network tab and reload the page.  Consider filtering by "XHR" requests, since it's almost certainly a problem there.  Look for the one with a status that's an error and click on it, then check the "Response" tab.  You'll find a more detailed error there.  The error will probably be more detailed if you [enable Debugging and Backtrace](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#changing-settings-in-the-ui).  Hopefully that should be enough to solve your problem, or at least update your question with more details!

[image]

Comment: No such luck using the developer tab - all A-OK there. I'm going to have to enable debugging and backtrace using by editing civicrm.settings.php cause my UI is borked. Stay tuned, and thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this occasionally after an upgrade. If you use memcache, restart the MySQL service. Also sometimes php opcache or APC needs clearing, try restarting your web server service, apache or nginx